# Android regex not acting as I thought it would

Tags: java, android, regex, numeric

I'm currently trying to create code to check if the content is Numeric. I found this neat matches command that can handle Regex code but I'm a begginner so It would be awesome if you could explain what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to involve E as an exponent and also that it works to type `.1` as well as `0.1`. Obviously, I don't want it to be possible to enter more then one punctuation mark and one E.

This is my code:

```
if (blabla.getText().toString().matches("((-|\\+)?([0-9]|[0-9].|.[0-9])+([0-9]+E)?([0-9]+)?)+")) {
```

At the moment, this code allows you to just enter something like E2 even though for me it looks like it shouldn't return that true because of the ([0-9]|[0-9].|.[0-9])+ in front of that.

Comment: What result are you seeing that you don't expect?

Comment: I'm expecting E2 not to match the content of the expression

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the periods:

```
if (blabla.getText().toString().matches("((-|\\+)?([0-9]|[0-9]\.|\.[0-9])+([0-9]+E)?([0-9]+)?)+");
```

If it is not escaped, a period means "any character except newline".

Comment: Thanks alot! That was the problem

Comment: @user1254588 hence accept this answer (green symbol on the left)